# Где взять библиотеку NLog.dll?

Tags: c#

**C#**
Пытаюсь установить NLog
Согласно инструкции скачал http://nlog-project.org/download/
В скаченном архиве данную библиотеку не нахожу.

Хотя может, что-то неправильно понял…

Comment: Добавить в решение библиотеку NLog через NuGet Package Manager

Comment: На указанной вами странице нет никакой ссылки на скачивание архива с библиотекой. Внимательнее прочтите что именно вы скачивали :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Package manager console( ***Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console***)

```
Install-Package NLog.Config -Version 4.3.11
```

Установить вам  NLog и NLog.Schema 
Как установить NuGet [тут](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/guides/install-nuget)

Comment: Вроде установил... Какую из библиотек требется подключать? http://prntscr.com/dh85ji

Comment: что вам нужен от этих библиотек ? Какая задача стоит ?